# How to create a QLinearGradient

Tags: c++, qt, qgradient, qlineargradient

At `qDebug() << gradient;`, it outputs:

> QBrush(QColor(Invalid),LinearGradientPattern)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLinearGradient gradient;
    QString gradientString = "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(15, 21, 255, 155), stop:1 rgba(126, 22, 224, 155));";
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setStyleSheet(gradientString);
    widget->setWindowTitle("StyleSheet");
    widget->show();
    
        // Parse the string to create a QLinearGradient

    // Remove the "qlineargradient(" and ")" parts
    gradientString.replace("background-color: qlineargradient(", "");
    gradientString.chop(2);

    // Extract the start and end points
    QRegularExpression rx("x1:([\\d.]+), y1:([\\d.]+), x2:([\\d.]+), y2:([\\d.]+)");
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match(gradientString);
    if (match.hasMatch())
    {
        float x1 = match.captured(1).toFloat();
        float y1 = match.captured(2).toFloat();
        float x2 = match.captured(3).toFloat();
        float y2 = match.captured(4).toFloat();
        qDebug() << "x1:" << x1 << "y1:" << y1 << "\nx2:" << x2 << "y2:" << y2 << "\n";

        gradient = QLinearGradient(QPointF(x1, y1), QPointF(x2, y2));

        // Extract the color stops
        QRegularExpression rxStop("stop:([\\d.]+) rgba\\((\\d+), (\\d+), (\\d+), (\\d+)\\)");
        int pos = 0;
        while ((match = rxStop.match(gradientString, pos)).hasMatch())
        {
            float stop = match.captured(1).toFloat();
            int r = match.captured(2).toInt();
            int g = match.captured(3).toInt();
            int b = match.captured(4).toInt();
            int a = match.captured(5).toInt();

            qDebug().nospace() << "stop: " << stop << " rgba(" << r << "," << g << "," << b << "," << a << ")\n";

            // Check if the color values are valid
            if (r >= 0 && r <= 255 && g >= 0 && g <= 255 && b >= 0 && b <= 255 && a >= 0 && a <= 255)
                gradient.setColorAt(stop, QColor(r, g, b, a));
            else
                qDebug() << "Invalid color values";

            pos = match.capturedEnd();
        }
        qDebug() << gradient;
    }

    widget = new QWidget;
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(widget->backgroundRole(), QBrush(gradient));
    widget->setPalette(palette);
    widget->setWindowTitle("Palette");
    widget->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

What's wrong in the way I'm creating the `QLinearGradient`?

Answer (score 1):

[G.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m) said:

> Note that there doesn't appear to be any suitable `qDebug()` overload for `QLinearGradient` as far as I can see, so the code appears to be relying on some undocumented API. Indeed, if I use `qDebug() << ...` on a `QLinearGradient` I *know* to be valid I see the same message.

[Example from Qt Forum *QGradient showing invalid color?*](https://forum.qt.io/post/672873):

```
QLinearGradient validGradient(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(100, 100));
validGradient.setColorAt(0, Qt::green);
validGradient.setColorAt(1, Qt::red);
qDebug()<<validGradient;
```

This outputs:

```
QBrush(QColor(Invalid),LinearGradientPattern)
```

---

The problem now is not about the gradient being invalid, but about how you construct the `QLinearGradient`.

In your case, you're creating `gradient` this way:

```
gradient = QLinearGradient(QPointF(x1, y1), QPointF(x2, y2));
```

Where `x2` gets the value of `1` from the stylesheet, instead of the widget's width, since the default [`coordinateMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgradient.html#coordinateMode) for `QGradient` is [`QGradient::LogicalMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgradient.html#CoordinateMode-enum):

> This is the default mode. The gradient coordinates are specified logical space just like the object coordinates.

`QGradient::StretchToDeviceMode` says:

> In this mode the gradient coordinates are relative to the bounding rectangle of the paint device, with (0,0) in the top left corner, and (1,1) in the bottom right corner of the paint device.

So you could set your `QLinearGradient`'s `coordinateMode` (after you initialize it with the values from the stylesheet) to it to be able to use the values from your stylesheet.

---

To use the default `coordinateMode`, you could use the following approach which is already shared as an answer on [Paint QPushButton with QLinearGradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304794/paint-qpushbutton-with-qlineargradient) by [cbuchart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307055/17726418), however I will be adjusting it to your case:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class GradientAdjuster : public QObject
{
public:
    GradientAdjuster(QLinearGradient& gradient, QObject *parent = nullptr) : _gradient(gradient), QObject(parent) {}

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
        {
            QWidget *widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(watched);

            //adjust the QLinearGradient based on the widget's size
            _gradient.setFinalStop(widget->width(), 0);

            QPalette palette = widget->palette();
            palette.setBrush(widget->backgroundRole(), QBrush(_gradient));
            widget->setPalette(palette);
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }

private:
    QLinearGradient& _gradient;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLinearGradient gradient(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(1, 0));

    gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt::darkRed);
    gradient.setColorAt(1, Qt::darkBlue);

    QWidget widget;
    //feed it the resulting gradient and install it on the widget as an event filter
    widget.installEventFilter(new GradientAdjuster(gradient, &widget));

    widget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Basically, you'd have to adjust the gradient color whenever the widget resizes.